# A "Theory vs. Empirical Research" Tag?

Tags: discussion

Based on this question:

[How to filter data obtained with practical measurements and simulations to be concisely put into a paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20324/how-to-filter-data-obtained-with-practical-measurements-and-simulations-to-be-co)

Currently, it's got two tags - "journals" and "computer-science", but once you ignore the specifics of it being about a paper looking at FPGAs, it stops being about computer science and becomes more about how to synthesize theoretical and empirical/applied research. That applies to a number of fields, and none of our tags seem to describe this yet - "theory" comes closest, but only touches on one half of the problem.

Any suggestions for a new tag?

Answer (score -1):

That question is borderline off-topic anyways (it already has 4 off-topic close votes on it). I don't think a new tag is necessary.

Comment: Eh, it was more inspired by that question, more than "it needs a new tag". It's something I struggle with a lot - what do you do if half the journals you publish in don't ping as "Good" to half your tenure committee, etc.